# can't be able to understand $_post in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

using codeigniter mvc pattern I create form in view that take only two values form user

```
<form action="<?php base_url(); ?> blogs/new_post" method="POST">
        <label>Title</label>
        <input type="text" name="post_title" />
        <label>discription</label>
        <input type="text" name="post_detail" />
        <input type="submit" value="post" />
    </form>
```

now when i submit the form, data  goes to the controller now here confusion created in my code that i can't able to understand i use  three cases in controller fist is if i use !empty($_POST) in controller and in view weather i fill the form or not fill the form message displayed in controller  is post 
my question is why always displaying post why not displaying not a post when i fill nothing in the form

```
if(!empty($_POST)) {
            echo "post";
        } else {
            echo "not a post";
        }
```

my second question is same related to the first condition now i use isset instead of !empty

```
public function new_Post() {
        if(isset($_POST)) {
            echo "post";
        } else {
            echo "not a post";
        }
    }
```

in this case either i fill form or not fill form when i submit the form the result always same that is "post"
and in third case if i use !isset the the result is always not a post eiter i fill or not fill the form
hope so you will understand my problem when i comes to if(!empty($_POST)) this condition then my mind is confuse what is the purpose of $_post

Comment: in general you will always use form validation to check the form fields and if anything has been filled out. take some time and work through the tutorial to learn the basics first: http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/index.html

Comment: Codeigniter form validation is good http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html but you also can use `$this->input-post('post_detail');`

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using the whole global variable $_POST to check empty and isset(). $_POST is not empty when you click on the button. You just Print_r the $_POST it will have the value of submit button. You need to print the value of $_POST on click and see the values in the array

Comment: In codeigniter the better solution would be using $this->input->post()

Comment: i understand your comment tell me how can i check weather this is post data coming form view with example and link

Comment: confusion clear i got my answer .......... the answer is very simple when i click submit form button then the result is always post .......know i create and other link in view <a href="<?php base_url(); ?> blogs/new_post">in new form controller </a> form data and this link goes to the same controller know my answer comes "not a post " . i always click form submit that is post weather this is null or full with field means when i click submit button this means post anchor is not ka post so result is not a post know i understand what is happen in my code

Comment: if($_POST){ echo "post";}else {echo "not post data ";} now this condition working correctly

Answer (score 0):

Well, in CodeIgniter (and most of the framework) doesn't allow you to access $_POST directly due to security reason.

You must access **$_POST** values through **$this->input->post()**

For more information read Input Class from CodeIgniter's docs
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html

Comment: I won't downvote you - but thats not true at all. you are just encouraged to use the Input Class but not required. think of it this way - anything you can do with the version of PHP you are using - you can do in codeigniter.

Answer (score 0):

$_POST is exist   when you click on the button:
so `empty` and `isset` cant work Correctly

the value at the first is

```
Array
(
)
```

SO U should  check

```
if($_POST)
```

instead

```
if(!empty($_POST))  OR if(isset($_POST))
```

AND best way  is   u check

```
if ($this->input->post())
```